# get all parent and children by using get_the_term

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got a problem. I was looking for getting Parent + each Child name (or slugs) in hierarchical form and assigned it to each variable on wordpress.

my taxonomy is like:

Fertilizer
-powdery
--p1
--p2
-liquid
--l1
--l2

Insecticide
-powdery
--p1
--p2
-liquid
--l1
--l2

I want to use it in the single page .

Comment: Try this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/

Comment: No Fertilizer and Insecticide are first level of taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers
I solved my problem :

```
    $cat1 = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'cypress_tax_products', array('parent'=> 0) );
    $cat2 = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'cypress_tax_products', array('parent'=> $cat1[0]->term_id) );
    $cat3 = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'cypress_tax_products', array('parent'=> $cat2[0]->term_id) );
```